# Create an array using two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create an array using two arrays. The first array contains Strings.
The second array contains numbers. I want to create a third array such as for example:

```html
1st array:
array:2 [▼
  0 => "Test"
  1 => "People"
]

2nd array:
array:2 [▼
  0 => "3"
  1 => "2"
]

3rd array:
array:5 [▼
  0 => "Test"
  1 => "Test"
  2 => "Test"
  3 => "People"
  4 => "People"

]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: `foreach` and `array_fill`?

Comment: "I want" is not a question. Show some attempts.

Comment: I tried to do a foreach, but i'm doing soime mistakes for sure. I don't know how to repeat those strings @AbraCadaver

Comment: @u_mulder Yes, sorry. My bad. I wanted to say that it is my goal, but i'm having some trouble

Comment: @AbraCadaver I tried to implode and str_repeat. Then explode into an array. But that's not very good for me..

Comment: That's not at all what I said.  You only need the two I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$firstArray = [
    0 => 'Test',
    1 => 'People'
];
$secondArray = [
    0 => '3',
    1 => '2'
];
$thirdArray = [];
foreach ($secondArray as $key => $array) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= (int)$array; $i++) {
        $thirdArray[] = $firstArray[$key];
    }
}
var_dump($thirdArray);
```

output

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Test"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Test"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "Test"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "People"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "People"
}
```